# Trying to get the max value of two bands and put in to array or variable in GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine, array

I'm trying to do an array with the maximum value of bands obtained by `Reducer.max()` with the objetive to get the max value of two bands with `Math.max()` but in the moment that I tried to make this, obtain a NaN in the console.

```
//MAXIMO B1 FECHA 1

var IMGLandsat5= ee.ImageCollection ('LANDSAT/LT05/C01/T1_TOA')
.filterDate ('2000-10-01', '2001-03-31')
     .filterBounds (geometry)
  .filterMetadata ('CLOUD_COVER', 'Less_Than', 20);
var Landsat5Filtro = ee.Image(IMGLandsat5.median());
var Landsat5Clip = Landsat5Filtro.clip (geometry);


var b1_1max = Landsat5Clip.select('B1');
var b11max = b1_1max.reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.max(),
  scale: 30,
  maxPixels: 1e10
});

var b11Max = b11max.get('B1');
print (b11Max);

//MAXIMO B1 FECHA 2

var IMGLandsat52= ee.ImageCollection ('LANDSAT/LT05/C01/T1_TOA')
.filterDate ('2010-10-01', '2011-03-31')
     .filterBounds (geometry)
  .filterMetadata ('CLOUD_COVER', 'Less_Than', 20);
var Landsat5Filtro2 = ee.Image(IMGLandsat52.median());
var Landsat5Clip2 = Landsat5Filtro2.clip (geometry);

var b1_2max = Landsat5Clip2.select('B1');
var b12max = b1_2max.reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.max(),
  scale: 30,
  maxPixels: 1e10
});

var b12Max = b12max.get('B1');
print(b12Max);

// ARRAY PARA OBTENER MAXIMO DE LAS DOS FECHAS 
var num = [b11Max,b12Max];
var max_total = Math.max.apply(null, num);
print(max_total);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`b11Max` and `b12Max` are Earth Engine server-side objects which are not available to client-side functions like `Math.max.apply()`. If I understand your analysis, the Earth Engine server-side equivalent would be:

```
// ARRAY PARA OBTENER MAXIMO DE LAS DOS FECHAS 
var num = ee.List([ee.Number(b11Max), ee.Number(b12Max)]);
var max_total = num.reduce(ee.Reducer.max());
print(max_total);
```

The ["Client vs. Server"](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/client_server) section of the developer guide can provide further detail.

Comment: I really apreciate your answer my dear friend